# Listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA : ORA-12504

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, oracle, oracle11g

On a c# application, I'm trying to get a connexion to a distant Oracle Server.

This is my connexion chain:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx;User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxx; Integrated Security=True")
```

I have never performed an OracleConnection and I'm not at ease with this..
Firstly, Visual studio told me I had to install install an Oracle Client. I have now the Oracle 11g Client Release 2.

Now when I try to connect to the OracleDB, I have the error message: ORA-12504:Listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

I suppose I have to add a Service Name into my OracleConnection chain like this:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx;User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=True;Service Name=Oracle")
```

There I have a new error message: Keyword not handled:service name

If anybody has already performed an Oracle connection from visual studio (I'm on Ultimate 2013), a few help won't be in denial.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but thought I ran into the issue today so I thought it may help someone:

I had a similar issue and it ended up being that my Connection string was specifying the incorrect Data Source name.  It has the match the entry you have in the TNSNAMES file on the server, and mine didn't.